# Where to find the COM error codes for the Windows Runtime?

Tags: error-handling, windows-runtime

Since we have to deal with COM error codes (HRESULT values) when working with the Windows Runtime I would like to know where I could find information about the error codes. I of course tried Google but only found the codes for Desktop apps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The may be identical, but the Windows Runtime certainly adds error codes to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation to which you linked (["COM Error Codes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542642.aspx)) should contain all of the standard HRESULT values.  Note that there are also [system error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx) which can appear as HRESULTs.

The standard HRESULTs and error codes are also defined in the `<winerror.h>` header, which is part of the Windows SDK (this header also defines the `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32` function, which can be used to convert a system error code into the equivalent HRESULT.

Note that other components (e.g. third party components) may use other HRESULTs.  Each component should document which HRESULT values it uses and what their meanings are.

Comment: Thanks James. winerror.h was a very helpful hint (I am not a C++ programmer). I was hoping that it would be a bit easier to get information about the possible HRESULT codes in WinRT (and hence easier to catch known errors in .NET that are not mapped to non-generic exceptions). Like finding out, what 0x800700CE means for example. In my understanding I first should check if this is a known HRESULT value. If not I could try to extract the error code from it, which in some cases may fail (according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/03/942851.aspx).

Comment: @JürgenBayer:  That is `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE`:  The facility (`7`) is Win32; the error code is `0xce`, which is `206` in decimal, which in `<winerror.h>` is that error.  It may take some work, yes.  I remember hearing of a tool to do error code lookups, but I don't remember anything else about that.  The debugger wraps `GetLastError()` using the `@err` psuedovariable in the Watch Window, but this doesn't work for arbirary calls, only calls that set the last error.